# Mutex lock ordering

Tags: c++, mutex

Just a simple question, given a read/write lock against the same data, with a very large amount of threads fighting to obtain the lock, can I be sure that one of this thread will get the lock at a certain moment ? I know there's no ordering in the schedule do release the lock to a particular thread, but is that totally random ?
Basically I may have 16 reading threads, and 1 writing thread, even the 16 are idling on a conditional variable, can I be sure that the writing one will get the lock ???

Comment: Depends on the implementation.

Comment: it changes between posix and win threads ?

Comment: No, this is not the kind of scenario where a simple mutex can get the job done.  You need a [reader-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock).  Don't write your own.

Comment: i was thinkg about a reader-writer lock, does the c++11 or boost ones take cares of giving priority to the writer ?

Comment: 16 readers and 1 writer looks like something that calls for [RCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update). Which can be implemented in 10 lines of C++ code using a combination of `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. Although you'll find opinions on the internet stating that `shared_ptr` _cannot_ be used for implementing RCU, I wouldn't be able to tell _why not_ if my life depended on it (as far as I can tell, it's perfectly suitable).

Comment: well, the concept here is to have a queue of items, and use several threads to process the queue in parallel (the read lock), while some other thread may put a write lock when need to modify the queue. I would like to be sure that the write lock does not get stuck because the reading threads are very fast so there's always something putting a read lock....

Answer (score 0):

If the readers are blocked on the *condition* variable, using `pthread_cond_wait()`, then yes. Because the writer won't be condition-waiting on it, I would hope for your sake.

Comment: that's ok but the incoming event may signal the readers continuously and they may have always a pending locker...